# 90s Sci-Fi show - Prisoner made from parts of other people

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I believe this show aired in the 90s. The main character was a prisoner with no past and he was made piecemeal of other people. There were no gross seams or anything but like one finger would be white with a long red nail, the next finger would be black, etc etc.

I don't remember a lot of other details, not sure that I ever finished the show.

Comment: What in the show makes it a science-fiction show? None of the details you've described stand out as particularly Science-fictiony. Can you also include ALL the details you do remember, holding back details just makes it more difficult to find.

Comment: @edlothiad a person assembled from pieces of others isn't SF/Fantasy?  How so?  Yes, we can do limb transplants now, but in the 90s that certainly was SF.

Comment: This reminds me a little of the second *X Files* movie -- one of the (male) characters, at one point, had an arm transplanted from a woman, Later in the film, there was a scene involving severing a head intended for transplant to another body.  Too late for your viewing date range, though.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I was trying to figure out what "piecemeal of other people" got it.

Comment: Sorry if I've not been clear enough. Mostly I just remember the odd look of the person and how he looked like a living jigsaw puzzle and the environment he was kept in being very sterile and white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is "Mr. Stitch", a TV movie that aired on the Sci-Fi Channel in 1995.  I remember watching at least part of this.  I definitely remember the main character was made up of parts of many different people, and the room he was kept in was white so as to not overwhelm his senses right after he woke up.

There is a brief description of the movie in *Variety*'s review at
http://variety.com/1996/film/reviews/mr-stitch-1200446390/

where they mention the patch-work appearance, the sterile white room, the main character prefers the name Lazarus, and was played by Wil Wheaton. (!)

Here is the summary from the top of the review:

> Title character (Wil Wheaton) who prefers to call himself "Lazarus," was created by team of scientists headed by Dr. Rue Wakeman (Rutger Hauer), using parts of more than 80 men and women of various ethnicities who have donated their bodies to science. Fortunately, in light of pic's two-hour timeslot, Lazarus comes pre-programmed to speak English and behave like a more-or-less human being -- though he's super-strong and looks like a patchwork quilt of various skin colors. Tom Savini's makeup work here is a terrific effect; like nothing you've seen before.

Comment: Sounds rather like a ripoff of Larry Niven's "The Patchwork Girl" -- one of his last "organ banks" stories.